# Unable to retrieve item from DynamoDB on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have an iOS application written in Swift.
I'm trying to retrieve an attributes for a specific item in my DynamoDB table, but instead I get an error.

AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
    let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:.USEast1, identityPoolId:"identityPoolId")
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:.USEast1, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

ViewController.swift:

```
import AWSDynamoDB

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let dynamoDBObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()

        dynamoDBObjectMapper.load(Book.self, hashKey: "7", rangeKey: nil).continueWith(executor: AWSExecutor.mainThread(), block: { (task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
            if let error = task.error as NSError? {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            } else if let tableRow = task.result as? Book {
                self.navigationItem.title = tableRow.name
            }

            return nil
        })
    }
}
```

In `ViewController.swift` I'm trying to get the name of the book from the table, and assign it to the navigation bar title.

Book.swift:

```
import AWSDynamoDB

class Book: AWSDynamoDBObjectModel, AWSDynamoDBModeling {

    var id: String?
    var name: String?

    class func dynamoDBTableName() -> String {
        return "Books"
    }

    class func hashKeyAttribute() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

When I run the app, I get the error message on the console, coming from ViewController.swift in the `if` statement:

```
Error: Error Domain=AWSMTLModelErrorDomain Code=1 "-[__NSSetI objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x618000244f50" UserInfo={AWSMTLModelThrownException=-[__NSSetI objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x618000244f50, NSLocalizedDescription=-[__NSSetI objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x618000244f50, NSLocalizedFailureReason=-[__NSSetI objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x618000244f50}
```

I tried to check whether this problem is about the configuration of AWS in my app by adding items using the app.
I followed AWS guide about saving an item to the DB, and it worked, so the problem is about how am I trying to receive the item.

Save an item = **Works**
Retrieve an item = **Doesn't Work**

Can you please help me solve it?

Comment: Could you provide more details? Are you setting up auth correctly? Also, from where are the items inserted? Do they have the same data type in the backend as specified in code?

Comment: @RohanDubal I've added my AWS configuration in `AppDelegate.swift` to the question. I set up auth correctly, as I followed the AWS guide, and I also checked if I can save an item to the DB, and I **can** save an item. The items are inserted manually to the DB by me. They do have the same data type as specified in the code on `Book.swift`.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it was because I set a String Set attribute like a String Array:

```
var strings: [String]?
```

Instead of like a String Set:

```
var strings: Set<String>?
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a try like this:

```
import AWSDynamoDB

class Book: AWSDynamoDBObjectModel, AWSDynamoDBModeling {

   @objc var id: String?
    var name: String?

   @objc class func dynamoDBTableName() -> String {
        return "Books"
    }

    class func hashKeyAttribute() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

I have the same issue as you. Saving an item to DynamoDB works well, but it doesn't work when loading (reading) an item from DynamoDB. Couldn't find any useful resources. Please let us know if you found any resolution. Thanks.